# Authorize.Net transaction VOID on already voided payment does not return an error code?

Tags: authorize.net

I have just started testing the VOID feature using an AIM call for Authorize.Net.  During my testing I found that if you issue a void in your application for a transaction that was previously **manually** voided inside the ANET interface, you will not receive an error response on your API call.  Instead it will seem like you still have successfully voided the payment from your application.

Does anyone know why this is the default behavior?  I guess it is okay that it doesn't throw an error, as long as the tran_id is correct. But it would be a little more correct if ANET passed back a message saying "transaction already voided" or similar.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Authnet themselves. You should ask on [their forums](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Authorize-Net-Community/ct-p/Community01).

Comment: I just tested both legacy and new integration API, both return a response reason code of 310, with message "This transaction has already been voided".

Comment: That helped me to track down the answer. It sends a reply code of 1 (success) a subcode of 1 (also success) but a response reason code of 310 (which means already voided) as you mentioned. I just needed to check the success condition for this special situation.